# Split a string column of DF to add extra column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has only 1 column, of the form

```
date, hh:mm - username/phonenumber: message
```

Example:

```
08/04/2021, 17:19 - Rajat: Let's go
```

I want to convert it into dataframe with columns:

```
date, hh, mm, username/phno, message
```

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Why not you post the code that you have given a try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) multiple times until you get what you want like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': "08/04/2021, 17:19 - Rajat: Let's go"}, index=[0])
df[['col2', 'col3']] = df['col1'].str.split("-", expand=True)
df[['date', 'hh:mm']] = df['col2'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
df[['username/phno', 'message']] = df['col3'].str.split(': ', expand=True)
df[['hh', 'mm']] = df['hh:mm'].str.split(':', expand=True)
# Delete leftover columns
df.drop(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'hh:mm'], axis=1, inplace=True)
# Change the order of the columns
df = df.loc[:, ["date", "hh", "mm", "username/phno", "message"]]
```